# Does a long-running query prevent an insert to tables involved?

Tags: sql-server

Say I have two tables:

```
Table 1
[Clustered Id]    [Text Field]

Table 2
[Clustered Id]    [Numeric Field]
```

Then I have a query:

```
select *
  from [Table 1]
      ,[Table 2]
 where [Table 1].[Clustered Id] = [Table 2].[Clustered Id]
   and [Table 1].[Text Field] like '%some string%'
```

Say my insert inserts one row, and looks like this:

```
insert into [Table 2]
values (new clustered ID)
      ,-182
```

If this query takes a long time to run, would an insert to `[Table 2]` be possible during that time? If so, what are the nuances? If not, what could I do to avoid it?

Comment: it depends ... this thread here will give you more information : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40987/does-a-simple-select-query-acquire-locks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes a select will take a shared lock that will prevent an update lock.

You could use the hint "with (nolock)" on the select so that it does not take shared lock and does not prevent an update lock.  But bad things could happen.  A lot of people on this site will tell you never to do that.

If an update it just taking a rowlock then only that row needs to be open.

On an update it really helps to add <> mirror to the set so it will not take a lock

```
update table1  
set col1 = 12  
where col3 = 56 
and co1 <> 12  -- will not take an update lock
```

An insert is different as it would only block on pagelock and tablock.
Please post your insert and how many rows you are inserting.

If you are taking a tablock then I think inserts would be blocked.  Even with repeatable read I don't think a select would block an insert.

Comment: If you are only inserting one row then you have nothing to worry about.  I have some tables with millions of rows and I need to insert 100,000 at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are in serializable isolation level,you don't need to worry.Your selects wont block   inserts..

Select Acquires shared locks.Talking about low level,SQL requires Exclusive lock on the row it is trying to insert.We also know Exclusive lock is not compatible with shared lock..Now a question arises ,how can a select will be blocked by an insert which doesn't have a row at all.

Isolation level determines how much duration the select locks will be held..In normal isolation levels,shared lock will be released as soon as the row is read ..

Only in serializable,range locks are taken and lock wont be released until the select is totally completed..